# PHP: Merging arrays

Tags: php, array-merge

Array 1:

```
Array (
    '127.0.0.1', 
    '235.107.12.3' 
)
```

Array 2:

```
Array (
    '34.235.54.6',
    '230.56.78.1'
)
```

Final Array should like below:

```
Array (
    [127.0.0.1] => Array (
        '34.235.54.6',
        '230.56.78.1'
    ), 
    [235.107.12.3]' => Array (
        '34.235.54.6',
        '230.56.78.1'
    ) 
)
```

Please give an advice as to how I can merge these two arrays (array 1 and array 2) to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [array_fill_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php):

```
$final = array_fill_keys( $array1, $array2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
$a = array_fill_keys($array1, $array2);
Print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array(
    [127.0.0.1]=>
        array
        (
          '34.235.54.6',
          '230.56.78.1'

        ), 
    [235.107.12.3]'=>
        array
        (
            '34.235.54.6',
            '230.56.78.1'
        ) 
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get your job done using loop, for eg. foreach loop here

```
foreach($array1 AS $val1)
{
    foreach($array2 AS $val2)
    {
         $newarr[$val1][] = $val2;
    }

}

print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $final = array();
    foreach($array1 as $k => $v)
        $final[$k] = $array2;

    var_dump($final);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$arrayA = array('127.0.0.1','235.107.12.3' );
$arrayB = array('34.235.54.6','230.56.78.1');
$i = 0;
foreach($arrayA as $a){
   $arrayC[$i] = arrayB;
$i++;
}
```

Comment: -1. `$i` remains zero and `arrayB` should be `$arrayB`. Also, please refrain from code-only answers: add some descriptive text, please.